# Manhattan distance for calculating the bisecting k-means instead of Euclidean distance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was asked to use manhattan distance for bisecting kmeans instead of euclidean distance in Spark.I tried changing it and use the code .But due to various private declarations and limited scope in existing code i am unable create a complete solution.Could somebody help me what other way i can do it?

Comment: Having your code would be quite helpful. Other than that, the best advice can be given is something you can google in 15 secods - euclidean distance is square root of squares of differences in each coordinate (i.e in case of two coordinates sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2), while manhattan distance is just a sum of coordinate differences (i.e. (x1-x2) + (y1-y2))

Comment: @J0HN I have used the below code to do the same  override def distance(v1: Vector, v2: Vector): Double = {
    validate(v1, v2)
    val b1=v1.asBreeze
    val b2=v2.asBreeze
    norm(b1 - b2, 1.0)
  } but the thing is i am unable integrate it with the spark.Due to spark code is closely coupled

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason why Spark chooses Euclidean distance without giving out an easy way to override it. You should be aware that **k-means is designed for Euclidean distance**. It might stop converging to optimal with other distances functions when the mean is no longer the best estimation for the cluster "centroid". Please see the below paper. http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume67/number10/pxc3886785.pdf

And here is the paper conclusion:

> As a conclusion, the K-means, which is implemented using Euclidean
>   distance metric gives best result and K-means based on Manhattan
>   distance metric’s performance, is worst.